# "Disciplined" badge remained after undeleting relevant question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Today I deleted a post of mine with 3 points and undeleted it later. There is this badge called **Disciplined** (*Delete own post with score of 3 or higher*), it was awarded and it remained even after undeleting it.

I guess this is a bug or am I wrong and this is an expected behavior?

As far as I can see, I am not supposed to own this badge anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular badges will not be revoked except in very special circumstances.

[How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

> Regular badges, however, once earned, are yours to keep. Even if the criteria by which you earned a badge have changed (the post was deleted, you got downvoted, etc.) you get to keep your badge. If you qualify for the same badge again (another post earns you a post-related badge, for example), you won't be penalized either (source).

Regular in this context is opposed to tag badges that come with privileges (e.g. a gold tag badge gives you the right to unilaterally close a question as a duplicate of another question with that tag).

Comment: One thing to be careful of is converting your posts to Community Wiki. It is possible to lose a tag badge if you do that. I've earned the golg Linux tag badge twice because of that.

Comment: @Iain: Yes, that's what I (or the authors of the linked text) mean with regular vs tag badge - if you drop below the threshold for a tag badge, it goes away, just like other rep based privileges.